# Analytic Solutions to differential (heat) equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I've searched around, but I couldn't find anything too helpful on the subject, so here goes. I am trying to find (if possible) an analytical solution to the differential equation of the form:
$$
\pm\frac{\partial F}{\partial \tau} = \frac{a}{x^{2/3}}F + \frac{b}{x} \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + c\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}
$$
where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are distinct constants, while $F = F(x,t)$. Owing to the similarity between this equation and a general diffusion equation, I have tried massaging it into various 'known' forms of such differential equations like
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \tau} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(g(x) \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \right) + h(x)F + \text{constant}\times F 
$$
but have so far been unable to yield anything useful. I am really quite novice when it comes to solving such ODE's (so I might be missing a trick), but am not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I might be completely over-complicating this; that's entirely possible.

Comment: This is not a non-linear equation.

Comment: @okrzysik That's very true; I was getting myself confused looking in the literature! Still stuck though unfortunately.

Comment: @PhysyCola : You are opening a too wide subject if you don't say what are the boundary and initial conditions.

Comment: @JJacquelin Ok, so if you need initial conditions; the condition on x would be that $F=0$ at $x \rightarrow \infty$, and $F = 0$ at $\tau \rightarrow \infty$ for the $+$ on the LHS, and $F = F_0$ at some $\tau = \tau_{max}$ for the $-$ on the LHS, with the aim of taking $\tau_{max} \rightarrow \infty$. Does that help?

Comment: Please make it less ambiguous. First condition :  $F(x\to \infty\:,\:\tau)=0$ but what is the value of $\tau$? . Second condition : $F(x\:,\:\tau\to\infty)=0$ but what is the value of $x$ ? Third condition : ... etc.

Comment: @JJacquelin I don't think that's an ambiguous condition; as the equation is separable, you don't need the values of $\tau$ and $x$ to be specified simultaneously.

Comment: See my answer below, which in fact is a comment (too long to be posted in the comments section).

Answer (score 1):

$$
\pm\frac{\partial F}{\partial \tau} = \frac{a}{x^{2/3}}F + \frac{b}{x} \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + c\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}
$$
With the method of separation of variables, one can find an infinity of particular solutions.

Let $F(x,\tau)=f(x)g(\tau) \quad\to\quad \pm\frac{g'}{g}=\frac{a}{x^{2/3}}+\frac{b}{x}\frac{f'}{f}+c\frac{f''}{f}=\lambda$
$$g(\tau)=e^{\pm\lambda\tau}$$
$f_\lambda(x)$ is solution of the ODE : $\quad cf_\lambda''(x)+\frac{b}{x}f_\lambda'(x)+\left(\frac{a}{x^{2/3}}-\lambda \right)f_\lambda(x)=0 $

The PDE is linear. So, a more general solution can be formally given in terms of infinite series (or finite series in some cases).

$$F(x,\tau)=\sum_{\text{any } \lambda}C_\lambda f_\lambda(x)e^{\pm\lambda\tau}$$
where $C_\lambda$ are constants to be determined to make $F(x,\tau)$ fit to the boundary and initial conditions.

The hitch is that the analytic solving of the ODE in order to express $f_\lambda(x)$ on closed form is certainly very arduous.

Moreover, the calculus of the coefficients $C_\lambda$ in order to satisfy the boundary and initial conditions is generally much too complicated (except in some particular and favorable cases, which is the raison of the necessity to precisely know how those conditions are).

Most likely, the analytical solving of the above PDE is not realistic. Numerical methods of solving are recommended.

Only in case of very favorable boundary and initial conditions this pessimistic opinion might be reconsidered.

Answer (score 0):

Try solving in Laplace space. The resulting ODE might not have analytical (already known) solutions, but one can still use asymptotic approximate methods.
Then anti transform the solution back to the “time” domain $\tau>0$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).